# How to print data in a template from multiple file in awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a main file `A.txt` (field separator = \t) :

```
Sample ID   Internal Control    Result  Consensus Sequence  Lane    Index Set   Index ID
2154686427  Pass    Detected    Not Available   1,2,3,4 1   UDP0001
2154666275  Pass    Detected    Not Available   1,2,3,4 1   UDP0002
```

And I have one file per sample that contain the same metrics, for example here `2154686427.mapping_metrics.csv` and `2154666275.mapping_metrics.csv` (field separator = ,).
`2154686427.mapping_metrics.csv`:

```
MAPPING/ALIGNING SUMMARY,,Total input reads,5654101,100.00
MAPPING/ALIGNING SUMMARY,,Number of duplicate marked reads,5577937,98.65
```

And `2154666275.mapping_metrics.csv`:

```
MAPPING/ALIGNING SUMMARY,,Total input reads,5651111,100.00
MAPPING/ALIGNING SUMMARY,,Number of duplicate marked reads,5511111,97.2
```

And I want to print the header ($3) and the corresponding value ($4) of each file in `A.txt`, like that:

```
Sample ID   Internal Control    Result  Consensus Sequence  Lane    Index Set   Index ID    Total input reads   Number of duplicate marked reads
2154686427  Pass    Detected    Not Available   1,2,3,4 1   UDP0001 5654101 5577937
2154666275  Pass    Detected    Not Available   1,2,3,4 1   UDP0002 561111  5511111
```

Do you have an idea in order to do that ?

I've tried to search similar problem based on FILENAME similarity but didn't find one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v OFS="\t" -F, '
  FS==","{
     hdr[FNR]=$3                         # save header in array
     sub(/\..*/, "", FILENAME)           # remove `.mapping_metrics.csv` from FILENAME
     sub(/.*\//, "", FILENAME)           # remove parent path from FILENAME
     val[FILENAME]=val[FILENAME] OFS $4  # append value to array using tab as separator
     next
  }
  FNR==1{
    print $0 OFS hdr[1] OFS hdr[2]       # print header and new header fields
    next
  }
  { print $0 val[$1] }                   # print record with new values
' *.mapping_metrics.csv FS="\t" A.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I try running it and as a result I have only the header that has been add to `A.txt`, not the corresponding value

Comment: Do you also get the original data rows without the new values or just the header?

Comment: I have also the original data

Comment: Make sure the prefix of the `*.csv` filenames matches the Sample ID.
The `sub(/\..*/, "", FILENAME)` replaces `.` and the following characters with an empty string leaving the Sample ID which needs to match `$1` of `A.txt`.

Comment: I was carefull about that. I found that the problem is that the *.csv file need to be in the same directory that A.txt because if I write `awk .... data/*.mapping_metrics.csv FS="\t" A.txt` the script doesn't work.

Also new question, it print all the value of the file; I made a subsampling of the real csv file for my example. So how can I choose (or print only those who have the header) the value that print on `A.txt` ? Thanks

Comment: No, you weren't. Because then the `FILENAME` would be e.g. `data/2154686427.mapping_metrics.csv` and doesn't match if we 
remove the `.mapping_metrics.csv` part. The `FILENAME` variable contains the given path to the input file, not just the filename.
I edited the answer to also remove the parent path. I don't understand the new question. What would be the expected output for your input files? 
Please edit your question and add the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F '\t' '
  BEGIN { OFS = FS; ORS = "" }
  NR==1 {
    h1 = "Total input reads"
    h2 = "Number of duplicate marked reads"
    print $0, h1, h2 RS
    next
  }
  {
    print
    FS = ","
    f = $1 ".mapping_metrics.csv"
    while (getline < f > 0)
      if ((h1==$3)||(h2==$3))
        print "", $4
    print RS
    close(f)
    FS = OFS
  }
' ./A.txt
```

Assuming the last two fields of the header can be hardcoded.

Comment: Thanks for the response. It works but  it print all the value of the csv file; I made a subsampling of the real csv file for my example. So how can I choose (or print only those who have the header) the value that print on A.txt ? Thanks

Comment: I have modified the code to take care of the requirement. Pls check.

Comment: Thanks to take the time to answer me. I checked the code and it print the correct value for the two column added , but it also print the last value an other time in the next column ; like this : `6785952 6519341 6519341` . You know why ?

Comment: It means that the input you are using is different than what you shared here. You need to post the same.

Comment: I double check and it seems that the input are the same as presented in the topic.